# Evaluate $\sum_{k=2}^{\infty}\left(\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} {1 \over k^n}\right)$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I am trying to evaluate

$$\sum_{k=2}^{\infty}\left(\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} {1 \over k^n}\right)$$
First observation: ${1 \over k^n} < 1$. So, in the limit, the sum of $p$ first terms of the inner sum is
$$\lim \limits_{p \to \infty}\left({1 \over k^2}{1 - {1 \over k^p} \over 1 - {1 \over k}}\right) =  {1 \over k^2}{1 \over 1 - {1 \over k}} = {1 \over k(k - 1)}$$
The outer sum now looks like this
$$\sum_{k=2}^{\infty}{1 \over k(k - 1)} = {1 \over 2} + {1 \over 6} + {1 \over 12} + {1 \over 20} + \dots$$
We know that ${1 \over k^2}$ converges, so the rewritten sum will converge as well. Do you have any ideas how to find the sum?

Comment: $$\frac{1}{k(k-1)} = \frac{1}{k-1} - \frac 1k$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint:

$$
\frac{1}{2}+
\color{blue}{\frac{1}{6}}+
\color{red}{\frac{1}{12}+}
\color{green}{\frac{1}{20}}+...=\frac{1}{2}+
\color{blue}{\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{3}}+
\color{red}{\frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{4}}+
\color{\green}{\frac{1}{4}-\frac{1}{5}}+...
$$

which is an example for a [telescoping series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telescoping_series)

Btw: You have proven that $\sum_{n\geq1}(\zeta(n)-1)=1$, congratulations :)

Comment: +1 if you put the phrase "Telescoping Series" in your answer so that he can research more into them.

Comment: @AlgorithmsX Enjoy! ;)

Comment: Thank you. It is near impossible to look up concepts in math without a connection to some name.

Comment: @tired That should do it! +1

Comment: @Dr.MV Thanks a lot (as always)